# How to do C++ template specialization on the stack without code dup?

Tags: c++, c++11, generics

How can I use template specialization on the stack? If `condition` is `constexpr` then this works in C++11:

```
bool condition=...;
MyClass<condition> myObj;
<20 lines using myObj>
```

**Goal: If `condition` is true I have other underlying member vars/func impl in `MyClass`.**

However this does not work of `condition` can't be determined at compile time.

**Is there a more elegant way than code duplication?:**

```
bool condition=...;
if (condition) {
 MyClass<true> myObj;
 <20 lines using myObj>
} else {
 MyClass<false> myObj;
 <20 lines using myObj>
}
```

I can also fix this with a Derived class but that I still can't use on the stack because I can't do:

```
bool condition=...;
condition ? MyClass myObj : MyDerivedClass myObj:
<20 lines using myObj>
```

I know other solutions:

- Use dynamic memory with eg a smartptr but i want to avoid this overhead etc:

```
myObjPtr=condition?new MyClass<true>() ? MyClass<false>();
<20 lines using myObjPtr>
```

- Place the 20 lines of code in a func and hope that inline will inline this in inner loop. However then my readibility is not great.

Comment: Perhaps a template is not the right solution here? What is the original, underlying and actual problem you're trying to solve? Why did you use a template class?

Comment: Encapsulation.  Put `<20 lines using myObj>` in a function and then the code becomes `if (condtion) do_foo(MyClass<true>{}); else do_foo(MyClass<false>{});`

Comment: What is _"men with eg"_? I am not a native English speaker so I really don't know and I really don't understand what you are asking because I don't understand your "other solution" where these _"dynamic men with eg"_ comes into play.

Comment: I added the goal and fixed some typos

Comment: @robert _"with eg a smartptr"_ - perhaps it'd be better if you didn't use abbreviations at all? You are mixing spoken language abbreviations with a programming type - and you miss both. `e.g.` and `std::unique_ptr` or _smart pointer_ would be clearer.

Comment: In your supposed dynamic solution, what type would `myObjPtr` be? Generally, `MyClass<true>` and `MyClass<false>` are two distinct unrelated classes, and you can't define a pointer that can point to an instance of either (well, other than `void*`).

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
auto twenty_lines = [&](auto&& myObj) {
  /* <20 lines using myObj> */
}

bool condition=...;
if (condition) {
 twenty_lines(MyClass<true>{});
} else {
 twenty_lines(MyClass<false>{});
}
```

Comment: Ah, I missed C++11 requirement. I don't think generic lambdas are supported in C++11.